# How do I use octave to find the numerical solutions to a system of non-linear equations?

Tags: math, octave

I have the following set of equations:

```
acos(x/250)=t
acos(w/300)=u
asin(y/250)=u
asin(z/300)=t
w-x=150
z-y=150
```

How do I solve this system of non-linear equations using octave? The only documentation I can find only shows an example of functions that are y=f(x), ie:
http://homepages.math.uic.edu/~hanson/Octave/OctaveNonlinearEG.html

Solving this system numerically is fine. (I would be curious about analytically too, but might not be possible of course)

Thanks!